# What is the difference between android.support.v4.app.fragment and androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-support-library, androidx

apparently there is a `X` under `import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity`, when I try to create a fragmentActivity. However, when I look for a sample project, it imports `android.support.v4.app.fragment` instead. May I know whats the difference, and why do I have this following error when I try to run my own project?:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.fragmenttest.helloapp.ui.collection.ViewPagerIndicatorActivity cannot be cast to androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.
```

Answer (score 2):

`android.support.v4.app.fragment` it's the package for the old Android support fragments.

`androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity` it's where the new fragments are. This came to replace the previous package because it's a much cleaner namespace. This is also known as Android X.

Probably the examples you're seeing are old and still use the old package. If I'm not mistaken Androidx was introduced 1 or 2 years ago.

In most cases you can simply replace the import, but I think the best way is to use Android Studio's [migrate to Androidx](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using different libraries.

`android.support.v4.app.*` is included in the **support libraries**.
`androidx.fragment.app.*` is included in the [**androidx libraries**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx).

They **can't** work together. Check the info to [migrate](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Then an `Activity` (or subclasses) **is not** a `Fragment`.
You **can't cast** a Fragment in an Activity.

Answer (score 0):

`Activity` != `Fragment`, your `java.lang.ClassCastException` is suggesting that you want to cast `Fragment` to `Activity`

`Activity` is full screen (mostly), `Fragment` is only a piece of look, kind of very extended `View`. One `Activity` can handle multiple `Fragment`s, e.g. on [bigger screens](https://medium.com/@elye.project/activities-or-fragments-a-little-sharing-c1ddc1041f79).

`FragmentActivity` was introduced in support pack for handling all `Fragment`s features in lower OS versions, now you should use `AppCompatActivity` which `extends FragmentActivity`